# Using single UIView I want to manage tap action based on location and update specific object

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoMCx.jpg)

I am making app like sudoku (9*9 boxes) but it has only binary choices (on/off) and using button gave me horrible results. Can anyone give me demo version of 9*9 (or 3*3) box where depending upon the tap location, that specific box gets toggled (on/off)

Comment: What was the horrible result of using `UIButton`? Using 9x9 `UIButton`s will be the simplest way.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "Can anyone give me <completed project> to <solve my problem>" is not a question, it's a request for others to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom subclass of UIView that had an attached tap gesture recognizer and interpreted the tap location to figure out which cell is being tapped, but it would be a lot of work.

It would be better to have custom view that contains a grid of buttons and set up the button actions to do what you want.

You said "...using button gave me horrible results." Can you elaborate? That should be a good way to go, so any "horrible results" are likely the result of something you did wrong, rather than that being the wrong way to go.

Comment: Actually I created 81 buttons and connected each one manually via story board. Also given the tag 1 to 81. But to do anything like change button1.color, I needed to put that in switch statement (I believe that there must be other way to do it.) And that seem like doing a lot of work for negligible thing.